# Passing a function through onPress in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is supposed to keep track of a list of items entered by the user. The list is initially empty. The user can enter an item name and item quantity and then press the "Add Item" button. Any ideas how I can pass a function through the onPress to get the items inputed by the user to display on the screen?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Button, FlatList } from 'react-native'
    

const ItemListScreen = () => {
    const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState([
        
    ]);
    
    return <View>
        <Text> Enter Item Name: </Text>
        <TextInput style = {styles.input}/>

        <Text>Enter Quantity: </Text>
        <TextInput style = {styles.input}/>
        <Button
        title="Add Item"
        onPress = {() => {
            setUserInput([...userInput()]);
            
            
        }  
    }
        
        />
         <FlatList
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.userInput}
    data = {userInput}
    renderItem = {({ userInput }) => {
        return (
            <View>
         <TextInput style = {fontStyle.input} />
         </View>
        );
    }}
    />

    </View>


};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    input: {
        margin: 15,
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 1,
        
    },
    fontStyle: {
        fontSize: 20
    }


    
});

export default ItemListScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to introduce some state variables for `name` and `quantity` and set the values when they are changed via the `onChangeText` prop of `TextInput`.

Then, when you are ready to add your item to your `FlatList`, you use the `onPress` prop of the button to set the state of `userInput` which becomes the value of the `data` prop of `FlatList`.

You set the user input state by creating a new array with the existing array items `...userInput` and a new item object created from the input values `{ name, quantity }`.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';

const ItemListScreen = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState([]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Enter Item Name:</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={(value) => setName(value)}
      />
      <Text>Enter Quantity:</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={(value) => setQuantity(value)}
      />
      <Button
        title="Add Item"
        onPress={() => {
          setUserInput([...userInput, { name, quantity }]);
        }}
      />
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
        data={userInput}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>Item name: {item.name}</Text>
              <Text>Item quantity: {item.quantity}</Text>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    margin: 15,
    padding: 10,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
  fontStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  item: {
    padding: 10,
    margin: 10,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
});

export default ItemListScreen;
```